# How can I find all usages of template in insert options?

Tags: content-editor, link-database

Doing a template refactor, I wanted to add a new base template and move a lot of scattered functionality to this template, including insert options. I did not know exactly where one specific template was configured as an insert option, so I checked the "Navigate" -> "Links". However, every content item using any template that had this single template as an insert option showed up in the list of links (apologies for the large black boxes; had to blank out client content):

[image: a small fraction of the links to this one template]

I could browse through this list and find all of the "__Standard Values" items, but that's not very smart (I'm a human, I could very easily miss one or more). Is there a way for me to do a smarter search?

Sitecore 7.2 rev 140526

Comment: Just to clarify, the ask is to identify templates that have a certain item as an insert option?

Comment: Some very strange dude said today that the answer to all questions is Sitecore Powershell (SPE). In this case he's probably right. And I'm sure someone here can help you with the command - I had too much drinks already to do that now :)

Comment: @DanSolovay: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @Gatogordo: If SPE works with 7.2, then that's probably a good thing to make as an answer :) I don't know if installing SPE is an option for me in this case though.

Comment: Didn't want to answer without a real command to go along.. and like I thought they are others who could pick up were I left..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In my humble **Opinion 3** is the best as it works out of the box, no modules required, no code required and what is more important you do not rely on `LinkDatabase` which can be sometimes outdated.

**Option 1**

If you can use [Sitecore PowerShell Extensions](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_PowerShell_console.aspx) for that. Here you go, complete code snippet

```c#
$item = Get-Item -Path "/sitecore/templates/Project/Playground/Page" 
[Sitecore.Globals]::LinkDatabase.GetItemReferrers($item,$true) | %{ $_.GetSourceItem()} | ? { $_.Name -eq "__Standard Values"}
```

**Option 2**

You can easily translate it into C# code and run it in some aspx page to display results.

```c#
var item = Sitecore.Data.Database.GetDatabase("master").GetItem("/sitecore/templates/Project/Playground/Page");
var itemReferrers = Sitecore.Globals.LinkDatabase.GetItemReferrers(item, true)
    .Select(link => link.GetSourceItem())
    .Where(i => i.Name.Equals("__Standard Values"));
```

**Option 3**

Using modified *@dan-solovay* approach, get results using Sitecore query:

Open url:
http://domain/sitecore/shell/default.aspx?xmlcontrol=IDE.XPath.Builder

Run query:

`/sitecore/templates//*[@@name = '__Standard Values' and Contains(@__Masters, '{92CF4650-4D5C-4A55-9A56-651858682E6D}')]`

[image]

PS.

Don't forget to change an ID ;)

Comment: Keep in mind that folder items may often have their insert options set directly instead of on their standard values.

Comment: Nice out of the box solution with #3.

Comment: You could also combine option 1 and 3 to at least not rely on the links db.

Answer (score 8):

One option is to use Sitecore Rocks to identify the items. This syntax will work if you are searching for items with an insert option set to a template with ID of {8FAD3C40-C1CC-4C4E-A3D9-F6F6BB20571D}.

```
select * from /sitecore/content//*[Contains(@__Masters, '{8FAD3C40-C1CC-4C4E-A3D9-F6F6BB20571D}')]
```

Note that the guid must be uppercase, as `Contains` is a text match operator.

If this is on a production environment, you could copy the database down to a development machine, run the query, and identify the item IDs that are impacted.  You can use "Export as CSV" to put these to a report.

[image]

Comment: As Alan notes above, my query should be modified to restrict to standard values items.

Answer (score 1):

Another Option, available since Sitecore 7.0, there has been an admin tool called LINQ ScratchPad.

You would simply adjust the LINQ Query as needed (similiar to Option 2) above, except no ASPX needed:

```
var item = Sitecore.Data.Database.GetDatabase("master").GetItem("/sitecore/templates/Project/Playground/Page");
var itemReferrers = Sitecore.Globals.LinkDatabase.GetItemReferrers(item, true)
    .Select(link => link.GetSourceItem())
    .Where(i => i.Name.Equals("__Standard Values"));
```

https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecore_7_development_team/posts/sitecore-7-linqscratchpad